# chai-http installs a deprecated version of formidable

Tags: superagent, formidable, chai-http

When I install chai-http it warns that formidable 1.2.6 is deprecated, and even though this is a dev dependency, when I push to my server the node app fails when asking it to npm install.

formidable is actually a dependency of superagent

I've tried updating chai-http, superagent and formidable, but my package.lock.json reference of "formidable": "^1.2.0", never gets updated.

npm outdated --depth=5 doesn't show me formidable as being installed but its in my package.lock.json under superagent, and that's where the error log points.

At present my workaround is to remove chai-http before pushing to server.

How can I update the formidable module?